# Access config file from any directory?

Tags: ruby, bash, yaml, thor

I am making a command line tool and I am using yaml to make a config file. But right now I can only access the tool when I am in the same directory as that of `myprogram.yml`.

```
private

CONFIG_FILE = 'myprogram.yml'

def write_config
  config = {}
  config['username']=@username
  config['password']=@password
  File.open(CONFIG_FILE, 'w') do |f|
    f.write config.to_yaml
  end
end

def read_config
  config = YAML.load_file(CONFIG_FILE)
  @username = config['username']
  @password = config['password']
end
```

How can I make this file to be accessed from any directory on my computer?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to give the absolute directory of the `myprogram.yml` file.  Right now it will look in the directory where you are executing the ruby script from.  By making it absolute, the script can run anywhere and know where to find the config file.

Example:

```
private

CONFIG_FILE = '/Users/myuser/config/myprogram.yml'

def write_config
  config = {}
  config['username']=@username
  config['password']=@password
  File.open(CONFIG_FILE, 'w') do |f|
    f.write config.to_yaml
  end
end

def read_config
  config = YAML.load_file(CONFIG_FILE)
  @username = config['username']
  @password = config['password']
end
```

Comment: :As I am making a ruby gem and people might have different alternative directories this might not work. Is there any way I can do it so that it works for any directory structure? @CDub

Comment: I've never written a gem before.  Perhaps there is some method to call an install directory or a "source" directory for the gem, and you could store the yml file in there?